# "Status Detail: 5003 : Internal server error"

Tags: opayo

I'm trying to upgrade my payment form to work with v3.00 of the protocol. When POSTing my form to https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp I get:

"Status Detail:     5003 : Internal server error."

According to http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes/5003-error-internal-server-error, this means I must be using an old version of the protocol ... but I don't think I am:

```
<input type=hidden name="VPSProtocol" value="3.00">
<input type=hidden name="TxType" value="PAYMENT">
<input type=hidden name="Vendor" value="myvendorID">
<input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value= "<?php echo $sagePay->getCrypt(); ?>">
```

I'm using the library available from https://github.com/tolzhabayev/sagepayForm-php:

```
$sagePay = new SagePay();
$sagePay->setCurrency('GBP');
$sagePay->setAmount($basket[0]['price']);
$sagePay->setDescription('test');
$sagePay->setBillingSurname($name_ar[1]);
$sagePay->setBillingFirstnames($name_ar[0]);
$sagePay->setBillingCity($billing_address_ar[1]);
$sagePay->setBillingPostCode($billing_address_ar[3]);
$sagePay->setBillingAddress1($billing_address_ar[0]);
$sagePay->setBillingCountry('gb');
$sagePay->setDeliverySameAsBilling();
$sagePay->setSuccessURL('myurl');
$sagePay->setFailureURL('myurl');
```

As far as I can see, all the newly required fields are there, and if I test with the example supplied with sagepayForm-php, it works.

Do I need to somehow tell sagepay that I want to switch from using 2.23 to 3.00? I'm looking around on My SagePay, but can't see a protocol setting. I thought SagePay automatically detected the protocol being used (from the VPSProtocol form field)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell MSP that you are using the new version of the protocol. 5003 is indicative of an error within Sage Pay. If you can try it again, then get me the VPSTxID (probably in the URL of your failure), I can check it out for you....